# Could ObjectInputStream.readObject() return null?

Tags: java, io

Could ObjectInputStream.readObject() method return null?

Comment: You need to provide more information. In what context? (Show source when possible.)

Comment: You don't necessarily need context here.  It can be as simple as "no, `readObject` will never return `null`."  If context is needed, then the answer must be "yes, it could be null" in which case you should post that answer.

Comment: If it couldn't, it'd be tricky deserialising objects with `null` fields.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.

You can serialize `null` by passing it to `writeObject()`, therefore you can get it back from `readObject()`.

However, if you are asking about the case of error, the answer is no, since in the case of error `readObject()` throws an exception.