# NullPointerException is Getting Thrown on ArrayList.add(String)

Tags: java, android, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I am trying to add a string to an ArrayList that was previously pulled out of an Internal Storage file. However, a NullPointerException is thrown at this line.

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    createLayout();
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String tripName = tripNameET.getText().toString(); //tripNameET is the EditText that provides the String to be put in the ArrayList
...
    FileInputStream fis1 = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois1 = null;
    try {
       fis1 = openFileInput("names");
       ois1 = new ObjectInputStream(fis1);
       names = (ArrayList<String>) ois1.readObject();
       ois1.close();
       fis1.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
    names.add(tripName); //NPE is Thrown Here
...
  }
}
```

Comment: This simply means that names is null, so ois1.readObject() returns null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code inside your `try` block is failing and so `names` is never being initialized. You then get an error trying to add an item to `names`, which is still `null`.

---

**Edit:** A good way to debug this further would be to add some `Log` statements in between the lines in your `try` block to see which line is failing, then investigate that line further.

Try this:

```
try {
    Log.i("CHECKPOINT", "1");
    fis1 = openFileInput("names");
    Log.i("CHECKPOINT", "2");
    ois1 = new ObjectInputStream(fis1);
    Log.i("CHECKPOINT", "3");
    names = (ArrayList<String>) ois1.readObject();
    Log.i("CHECKPOINT", "4");
    ois1.close();
    Log.i("CHECKPOINT", "5");
    fis1.close();
    Log.i("CHECKPOINT", "6");
}
```

Now run your code again and check [logcat](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html) to see what the lasted logged out statement is.

---

**Edit 2:** If all six of those log statements print successfully, that would indicate that the `try` block is *not* failing. We do still know that `names` is null. Confirm this with the following code:

```
try {
    fis1 = openFileInput("names");
    ois1 = new ObjectInputStream(fis1);
    names = (ArrayList<String>) ois1.readObject();

    // indicates if names is really null
    Log.i("names is ", (names == null) ? "null" : "not null"); 

    ois1.close();
    fis1.close();
}
```

If are assumption is correct, and `names` is `null`, you need to do some investigation to find out why `ois1.readObject();` is returning `null`.

- Is the file `names` empty?
- Does it need to be named `names.txt`?
- In what scenarios would `.readObject()` return null?

Hope this helps, good luck :-)

Comment: How do I stop the try block from failing?

Comment: @JenglandDev Good question, I added some more information to my post.

Comment: They all were logged. Does a catch statement have anything to do with this?

Comment: Interesting, okay that actually means the try block is *not* failing. I'll update my answer again.

Comment: Btw, if you found this a helpful answer, mark it as correct :-)

Comment: Yeah, almost done doing a bit of editing, but I expect it to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

tripName is null that's why you are getting NPE when you try to add in list.
Just add a simple check before adding to list.

```
     if(tripName!=null){
        names.add(tripName);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that names is being deserialized from readObject() as null.

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172396/could-objectinputstream-readobject-return-null)